# Adding a back button

Tags: php, button

I want to add a back button to this php code I'm using. So once I enter in details and click "Register", I get ""New record is inserted sucessfully".

Which is great but I'd like to add a back button that can take me back to another page.

Below is my code. I have no idea where to place the back button either

```
<?php
 $FirstName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FirstName');
 $LastName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'LastName');
 $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
 $Email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
 $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
 if (!empty($username)){
if (!empty($password)){

$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "test";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_error()){
die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '
. mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
$sql = "INSERT INTO details (Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, Email)
values ('$username','$password','$FirstName','$LastName','$Email')";
if ($conn->query($sql)){
echo "New record is inserted sucessfully";
}
else{
echo "Error: ". $sql ."
". $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
}
}
else{
echo "Password should not be empty";
die();
}
}
else{
echo "Username should not be empty";
die();
}
?>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($conn->query($sql)){
    echo "New record is inserted sucessfully";
    echo '<button onclick="history.go(-1);">Back </button>';
}
```

OR

```
echo '<a href="' . echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '">Back</a>';
```

Comment: Great Tim that seems to work! Thanks a million. If I want to have the back button to a certain page rather than back to the starting page would it look something like this ? echo '<button onclick="http://localhost/LoginPage/Home.html">Back </button>';